# Subselect OrderBy primeira linha

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou fazendo o select abaixo mas no ultimo subselect (mileage) estou tendo problemas com o `ORDER BY` erro "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis", se eu remover o `ORDER BY` ele funciona.

```
SELECT /* DATE OF THE ROUTE */
       {GPS}.[DateTime],           
       /* ROUTE DESCRIPTION */                                     
       {Route}.[Description],
       /* NAME OF THE DRIVER */  
       {Driver}.[Name],                                                 
       /* VEHICLE LICENSE PLATE */
       {Vehicle}.[Registration],
       /* QUANTITY OF STOPS */
       (SELECT COUNT({RouteStop}.[RouteId])
          FROM {RouteStop}
         WHERE {RouteStop}.[RouteId] = {GPS}.[RouteId]) AS StopCount,
       /* AMOUNT OF FUEL */
       (SELECT SUM(FUEL.[Value])
          FROM {GPS} FUEL     
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = FUEL.[RouteId]
           AND FUEL.[EventTypeId] = 23) FuelAmount, /* Event Fuel */
       /* ROUTE STARTDATETIME */
       {GPS}.[DateTime] AS ROUTESTARTDATETIME,
       /* ROUTE ENDDATETIME */
       (SELECT ROUTEENDDATETIME.[DateTime]
          FROM {GPS} ROUTEENDDATETIME
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = ROUTEENDDATETIME.[RouteId]
           AND ROUTEENDDATETIME.[EventTypeId] = 5 /* Event Route Completed */
           AND ROWNUM = 1) AS ROUTEEND, 
       /* INITIAL MILEAGE */                         
       (SELECT MILEAGEBEGIN.[Value]
          FROM {GPS} MILEAGEBEGIN 
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = MILEAGEBEGIN.[RouteId] 
           AND MILEAGEBEGIN.[EventTypeId] = 21 /* Event Mileage */
           AND ROWNUM = 1
         ORDER BY MILEAGEBEGIN.[DateTime]
        ) AS INITIALMILEAGE

FROM {GPS}

INNER JOIN {Route}
    ON {GPS}.[RouteId] = {Route}.[Id]

 INNER JOIN {Driver}
    ON {GPS}.[DriverId] = {Driver}.[Id]

 INNER JOIN {Availability}
    ON {Driver}.[Id] = {Availability}.[DriverId]

 INNER JOIN {Vehicle}
    ON {Availability}.[VehicleId] = {Vehicle}.[Id]

 WHERE {GPS}.[EventTypeId] = 3 /* Event RouteStarted */
```

Tentei fazer da forma abaixo mas da o erro: "ORA-00936: missing expresion".

```
SELECT /* DATE OF THE ROUTE */
       {GPS}.[DateTime],           

       /* INITIAL MILEAGE */                         
       SELECT TEST,'more test' FROM (SELECT MILEAGEBEGIN.[Value] AS TEST
                                       FROM {GPS} MILEAGEBEGIN 
                                      WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = MILEAGEBEGIN.[RouteId] 
                                        AND MILEAGEBEGIN.[EventTypeId] = 21 /* Event Mileage */
                                      ORDER BY MILEAGEBEGIN.[DateTime] ASC
                                    ) 
                              WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AS INITIALMILEAGE

FROM {GPS}

 WHERE {GPS}.[EventTypeId] = 3 /* Event RouteStarted */
```

/********************* QUERY CORRIGIDA ********************************/

```
SELECT /* ROUTEID */
       ROUTES.[RouteId] AS ROUTEID,       
       /* ROUTE STARTDATETIME */
       ROUTES.[DateTime] AS ROUTESTARTDATETIME,     
       /* ROUTE DESCRIPTION */                                     
       {Route}.[Description],
       /* NAME OF THE DRIVER */  
       {Driver}.[Name],         
       /* VEHICLE LICENSE PLATE */
       {Vehicle}.[Registration],
       /* QUANTITY OF STOPS */
       (SELECT COUNT({RouteStop}.[RouteId])
          FROM {RouteStop}
         WHERE {RouteStop}.[RouteId] = ROUTEID) AS STOPCOUNT,
       /* AMOUNT OF FUEL */
       (SELECT SUM(FUEL.[Value])
          FROM {GPS} FUEL     
         WHERE ROUTES.[AvailabilityId] = FUEL.[AvailabilityId]
           AND TRUNC(ROUTES.[DateTime]) = TRUNC(FUEL.[DateTime])
           AND FUEL.[EventTypeId] = @FuelEventTypeId) AS FUELAMOUNT,
       /* ROUTE ENDDATETIME */
       (SELECT ROUTEENDDATETIME.[DateTime]
          FROM {GPS} ROUTEENDDATETIME
         WHERE ROUTEID = ROUTEENDDATETIME.[RouteId]
           AND ROUTEENDDATETIME.[EventTypeId] = @RouteCompletedEventTypeId 
           AND ROWNUM = 1) AS ROUTEEND, 
       /* INITIAL MILEAGE */                         
       (SELECT INITIALMILEAGE 
          FROM (SELECT MILEAGEBEGIN.[Value] AS INITIALMILEAGE
                  FROM {GPS} MILEAGEBEGIN 
                 WHERE ROUTES.[AvailabilityId] = MILEAGEBEGIN.[AvailabilityId]
                   AND TRUNC(ROUTES.[DateTime]) = TRUNC(MILEAGEBEGIN.[DateTime])
                   AND MILEAGEBEGIN.[EventTypeId] = @MileageEventTypeId 
                 ORDER BY MILEAGEBEGIN.[DateTime] ASC
               ) 
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1),
       /* FINAL MILEAGE */                         
       (SELECT FINALMILEAGE 
          FROM (SELECT MILEAGEEND.[Value] AS FINALMILEAGE 
                  FROM {GPS} MILEAGEEND 
                 WHERE ROUTES.[AvailabilityId] = MILEAGEEND.[AvailabilityId]
                   AND TRUNC(ROUTES.[DateTime]) = TRUNC(MILEAGEEND.[DateTime])
                   AND MILEAGEEND.[EventTypeId] = @MileageEventTypeId
                 ORDER BY MILEAGEEND.[DateTime] DESC
               ) 
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1)

FROM {GPS} ROUTES

INNER JOIN {Route}
   ON ROUTES.[RouteId] = {Route}.[Id]

INNER JOIN {Availability}
   ON ROUTES.[AvailabilityID] = {Availability}.[Id]

INNER JOIN {Driver}
    ON {Availability}.[DriverId] = {Driver}.[Id]

INNER JOIN {Vehicle}
   ON {Availability}.[VehicleId] = {Vehicle}.[Id]

 WHERE ROUTES.[EventTypeId] = @RouteStartedEventTypeId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você não pode usar o `order by` em uma subconsulta. [Essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119190/oracle-sql-order-by-in-subquery-problems?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) do *soen* é mais ou menos o mesmo ponto que a sua.

> Actually "ordering" only makes sense on the outermost query

Ou seja, você deve mover a ordenação para a consulta principal:

```
SELECT /* DATE OF THE ROUTE */
       {GPS}.[DateTime],           
       /* ROUTE DESCRIPTION */                                     
       {Route}.[Description],
       /* NAME OF THE DRIVER */  
       {Driver}.[Name],                                                 
       /* VEHICLE LICENSE PLATE */
       {Vehicle}.[Registration],
       /* QUANTITY OF STOPS */
       (SELECT COUNT({RouteStop}.[RouteId])
          FROM {RouteStop}
         WHERE {RouteStop}.[RouteId] = {GPS}.[RouteId]) AS StopCount,
       /* AMOUNT OF FUEL */
       (SELECT SUM(FUEL.[Value])
          FROM {GPS} FUEL     
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = FUEL.[RouteId]
           AND FUEL.[EventTypeId] = 23) FuelAmount, /* Event Fuel */
       /* ROUTE STARTDATETIME */
       {GPS}.[DateTime] AS ROUTESTARTDATETIME,
       /* ROUTE ENDDATETIME */
       (SELECT ROUTEENDDATETIME.[DateTime]
          FROM {GPS} ROUTEENDDATETIME
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = ROUTEENDDATETIME.[RouteId]
           AND ROUTEENDDATETIME.[EventTypeId] = 5 /* Event Route Completed */
           AND ROWNUM = 1) AS ROUTEEND, 
       /* INITIAL MILEAGE */                         
       (SELECT MILEAGEBEGIN.[Value]
          FROM {GPS} MILEAGEBEGIN 
         WHERE {GPS}.[RouteId] = MILEAGEBEGIN.[RouteId] 
           AND MILEAGEBEGIN.[EventTypeId] = 21 /* Event Mileage */
           AND ROWNUM = 1
        ) AS INITIALMILEAGE

FROM {GPS}

INNER JOIN {Route}
    ON {GPS}.[RouteId] = {Route}.[Id]

 INNER JOIN {Driver}
    ON {GPS}.[DriverId] = {Driver}.[Id]

 INNER JOIN {Availability}
    ON {Driver}.[Id] = {Availability}.[DriverId]

 INNER JOIN {Vehicle}
    ON {Availability}.[VehicleId] = {Vehicle}.[Id]

 WHERE {GPS}.[EventTypeId] = 3 /* Event RouteStarted */

 ORDER BY INITIALMILEAGE
```